# How to Make Organic Fade to Black in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working a retro/old-style video game, and I was wondering whether or not there is a way to create an organic fade-to-black, similar to what is found in the original NES console. I am aware of how to create a traditional fade-to-black screen, but it doesn't really fit the theme of my game. I'm using Unity 2019.4 LTS.

Here’s a example of a character about to exit the area and cause a fade to black:
[image]

Here’s what the organic fade looks like at 75% completion:
[image]

And here’s what a traditional fade looks like at 75% completion:
[image]

Comment: What distinguishes an "organic" fade to black from a "traditional" fade to black? Can you include image or animated examples to make sure your goal is clear for all readers?

Comment: @DMGregory Ok, I added some examples.

Comment: This is a cross-post of https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17559/what-causes-that-organic-fade-to-black-effect-in-classic-video-games

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from another StackExchange site. Please post each question on just one site in the StackExchange network, to gather the best answers in one place and avoid leaving dead ends for future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with changing brightness/contrast in post effect, there are many implementations for Unity available on the internet. As an example I just opened and modified image in paint.net:

[image]